# Python type annotation issues with inheriting types and members overload

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, type-annotation

Please see example below, with python 3.7, where I can't find the way to correctly annotate. The annotations errors are shown in comments, and are given by mypy.

- I have a "generic class" which implements "generic members". And concrete classes and members inheriting of that structure.
- The concrete members can have additional methods and use different arguments for the constructor.

What is the way to correctly annotate this?

Thanks a lot.

```
import abc
import typing


class ParentProvider(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass


class ChildProvider(ParentProvider):
    def __init__(self, who: str) -> None:
        ParentProvider.__init__(self)
        self._who: str = who

    @property
    def p(self) -> str:
        return "Hello %s" % self._who


class Parent(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def providerType(self) -> typing.Type[ParentProvider]:
        pass

    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def providerKwargs(self) -> typing.Dict[str, typing.Any]:
        pass

    @property
    def provider(self) -> ParentProvider:
        # How to avoid the following error?
        # error: Too many arguments for "ParentProvider"  [call-arg]
        return self.providerType(**self.providerKwargs)

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def useIt(self) -> None:
        pass


class Child(Parent):
    @property
    def providerType(self) -> typing.Type[ParentProvider]:
        # Using Type[ChildProvider] instead Type[ParentProvider]
        # doesn't helps
        return ChildProvider

    @property
    def providerKwargs(self) -> typing.Dict[str, typing.Any]:
        return dict(who='world')

    def useIt(self) -> None:
        # How to avoid the following error?
        # error: "ParentProvider" has no attribute "p"  [attr-defined]
        print(self.provider.p)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Child().useIt()
```

Comment: For the "Child.useIt" method, a workaround is "assert isinstance(self.provider, self.providerType)" before using self.provider.p. But this doesn't works in Parent.provider because it doen't know yet the final providerType type.

Comment: There are several unclear points here. You pass keyword arguments to `providerType`, but you didn't define it to accept any arguments. `providerKwargs` is a method, but you aren't calling it (you are treating it as a `dict` itself).

Comment: Thanks @chepner. The providerKwargs is used by the Parent when instatiating provider in the Parent.provider property.

Comment: It doesn't matter who uses it, because you are using it incorrectly. If it's a method, you have to *call* it: `return self.providerType(**self.providerKwargs())`. And you still need to change the signature of `providerType` to *accept* keyword arguments.

Comment: @chepner providerKwargs is a property...

Comment: You still have the problem of `providerType` not accepting the arguments you are trying to pass to it.

Comment: The called constructor is the one of ChildProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a "generic class" which implements "generic members"

Then mark it as such:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


_T = TypeVar('_T', bound='ParentProvider')


class Parent(Generic[_T], metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def providerType(self) -> typing.Type[_T]:
        pass

    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def providerKwargs(self) -> typing.Dict[str, typing.Any]:
        pass

    @property
    def provider(self) -> _T:
        return self.providerType(**self.providerKwargs)

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def useIt(self) -> None:
        pass
```

Now the specific `Child` impl becomes:

```
class Child(Parent[ChildProvider]):
    @property
    def providerType(self) -> typing.Type[ChildProvider]:
        return ChildProvider

    @property
    def providerKwargs(self) -> typing.Dict[str, typing.Any]:
        return dict(who='world')

    def useIt(self) -> None:
        print(self.provider.p)
```

> How to avoid the following error?
>
> ```
> error: Too many arguments for "ParentProvider"  [call-arg]
> ```

The `Parent.__init__` signature doesn't allow any arguments to be passed - you can loosen that with

```
class ParentProvider(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        pass
```

(or just

```
class ParentProvider(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        pass
```

if you don't want to allow positional args passed in providers constructors).